Balancing of a chemical reaction of oxidation of sulfides by ozone
My textbook mentions the following reaction:
$\ce{MS(s) + 4 O3(g) -> MSO4(s) + 4 O2}$ (where $\ce{M}$ = $\ce{Pb}$, $\ce{Cu}$, $\ce{Zn}$, $\ce{Cd}$)
$\ce{PbS(s) + 4 O3(g) -> PbSO4(s) + 4 O2}$
But if I use 2 molecules of ozone and one molecule of oxygen the reaction is still balanced.
Which approach is correct?
I don't think they will both be same because if we need to make calculations of moles of product consumed then each reaction would give a different mole ratio
Maybe knowing the mechanism might help me.

Guides for formatting of chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics / Detailed / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

The correct approach is – enumeration of reactions must be based on knowledge of chemistry of involved elements or substances. Formally correct, enumerated reactions may not reflect observed reality. You could write many formally correct but factually incorrect reactions.
Ozone $\ce{O3}$ and "normal" oxygen $\ce{O2}$ have different chemical behavior and are not freely interchangeable in chemical reactions.
You can formally substitute the reactant $\ce{4 O3}$ by other reactant $\ce{6 O2}$, or their combinations like $\ce{2 O3 + 3 O2}$, or by any other O3 and O2 combinations with the oxygen atom counts between 4 and 12. And with any amount of remaining oxygen from $\ce{0 O2 to 4 O2}$. But most of these combinations would be factually nonsenses.
The reaction $\ce{PbS + 2 O2 -> PbSO4}$ does not happen at room conditions. If it did, blackening ($\ce{PbS}$) of old paintings with lead white ($\ce{PbCO3 . Pb(OH)2}$) would not be a problem.
$\ce{O2}$ does not oxidize $\ce{MS}$ at room conditions. It can oxidize it, but at high temperatures and forming other products:
$$\ce{2 PbS + 3 O2 -> 2 PbO + 2 SO2},$$
resp.
$$\ce{3 PbS + 5 O2 -> Pb3O4 + 3 SO2}.$$
Ozone $\ce{O3}$ releases highly reactive atomic oxygen
$$\ce{O3 -> O2 + O}$$
that reacts with sulfides
$$\ce{MS + 4 O -> MSO4}.$$
